# Castle windsor logging facility

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I'm trying to remove some logging dependencies and stumbled across Castle Windsor's logging facility.  However, I'm kind of skeptical about whether I should use it or not.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Castle.Core.Logging.ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Windsor's logging facility requires that you expose your logger as a property.  Is that really a good practice?  I feel like I'm almost breaking encapsulation because normally when I reuse a component, I don't care about it's logging mechanism and I don't normally want to see it exposed.

If I use a custom wrapper that uses a static class to create the log, I can keep it private.  For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static MyCustomWrapper.ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));

    ...
}
```

I've searched the web for reasons why I should use the logging facility, but I'm only finding articles on ***how*** to use it, but not ***why*** I should use it.  I feel like I'm missing the point.  Having the logging component exposed is kind of scarying me away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Windsor's logging facility requires that you expose your logger as a property.

Not necessarily. You can also put your logger as a constructor (i.e. mandatory) dependency. The logger is usually declared as a property (i.e optional dependency) because there might be no logger. That is, the component should be able to function without a logger.

> If I use a custom wrapper that uses a static class to create the log

That's a service locator, that code couples `MyClass` to `LogManager`, which is IMHO worse than what you were trying to get away from.

Comment: But wouldn't I already be coupled to `Castle.Core.Logging.ILogger`?  Or is it because `LogManager` is a static class and I can't replace it?

Comment: @Ashley: exactly. There's much less coupling with an interface.